# How do I display the Morocco currency?

Tags: css

I want to display currency symbol for Morocco currency. I found in our project css file this code for the swiss currency :

```
.ikon-sign-chf:before {
  content: "\e911";
}
```

How is called the value `"\e911"` ? And what is the associated for morocco symbol ?

Comment: That's just an "escape sequence", used to specify a unicode codepoint. https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes _"And what is the associated for morocco symbol ?"_ - all it does, is specify which glyph out of a given font to use. Which glyph in whatever font you are using corresponds to the Moroccan currency symbol, we can't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS, the value "\e911" that you see is actually a **Unicode escape sequence**. Unicode escape sequences are used to represent characters that cannot be easily typed on a keyboard or are not directly available in the character set being used.

Now we now that we can look up the correct symbols:

```
د (Arabic Letter Dal): U+062F
. (Full Stop): U+002E
م (Arabic Letter Meem): U+0645
```

& Now render it inside html :)

```html
<p> &#x062F;&#x002E;&#x0645;</p>
```

Comment: when it is in css it should be : `content: "\062F\002E\0645";`